# The problem with tf.keras.datasets.imdb.load_data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, tf.keras

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                 num_words=10,
                                                 skip_top=0,
                                                 maxlen=None,
                                                 seed=42,
                                                 start_char=1,
                                                 oov_char=2,
                                                 index_from=3)

s = set()
for i in X_train:
  s.update(np.unique(i))
print(s)
>{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

My question is we have specified the `num_words` to be 10 and we want the 10 most frequent words.
But in the set `s` 1 = Start of a sequence, 2 = `oov_char` so we have only remaining six indices (4 to 9) representing words.

Why are we getting only six most frequent when we specified that the `num_words` must be 10?
In addition to can anyone explain the meanings of `index_from` and how are the indices allocated in the X_train with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You used the default inputs of imdb.load_data(). I think it's not really the number of words that returns, but the number of indexes that return. If you change the default input mode as shown below, you will see that 10 indices are returned.

```
from keras.datasets import imdb

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(
    path="imdb.npz",
    num_words=10,
    skip_top=0,
    maxlen=None,
    seed=42,
    start_char=0,
    #oov_char="OOV",
    index_from=0,
)

Set = set()
for i in X_train:
    Set.update(np.unique(i))

print(Set)
print(len(Set))
```

Output:

```
{'8', '6', '0', '7', '5', '2', '4', '9', '1', '3'} # + 'OOV' if uncomment oov_char="OOV"
10 # will be 11, if uncomment oov_char="OOV"
```

In this database, the num_words is usually given 10,000 which does not matter if it is exactly the same number or a little more or less.